# "Artists Take on Architecture"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

***"[Psycho Buildings: Artists Take on Architecture](http://www.southbankcentre.co.uk/find/hayward-gallery-and-visual-arts/hayward-gallery-exhibitions/past/psychobuildings-artists-take-on-architecture)"*** is the title of an exhibition.

Does it mean **"artists' understanding of architecture"**? Thus, is "take" here a noun? If so, wasn't it better to say "Artists' Take on Architecture"? Maybe it is OK to remove that apostrophe, since it is a title?

Comment: As the answer / comments below state, (a) deadrat's interpretation ('take on' = come to grips with) is demanded by the lack of apostrophe; (b) as Josh says, some people flout the rules, but then only they know 'what it means'; (c)  Spagirl is probably correct that this is a pun.

Comment: It may be deliberately ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with deadrat. Nothing about the title allows us to infer that the exhibition centers on 'artists against architects'- especially about the 'nature of buildings'.

"Take on" here can mean different things, but in this context it is most similar to "focus on", "tackles" or "engage with". This is a common phrase. See a popular tv series that uses it in the same way: [Tracey Takes On...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracey_Takes_On...)

As such, assuming some discord between artists and architects is incorrect. Rather, the artists will be tackling the philosophy or artistic nature of buildings- maybe in a complimentary way, critically, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bad guess.  One's *take* on a subject means how one views that subject.  But in this case, you've got the phrasal verb *take on*, meaning to engage in a dispute.  The title means that the artists are fighting with the architects about the nature of buildings.

The clue is that it's not OK to remove the apostrophe.

Comment: I am undecided between the meaning OP suggests and yours, they both sound correct, and the fact that the apostrophe is missing is not a big issue for "artists".

Comment: @Josh61 Anything's possible with the poseurs who call themselves modern artists and the dupes who call this stuff art.  But here's part of a review of the "exhibition": *In an exhausting and painstaking process Nelson has taken an axe to one of the galleries to create a scene of utter devastation*. (http://www.dezeen.com/2008/05/31/psycho-buildings-at-the-hayward/) I'm gonna go with the oppositional sense of *take on*, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It is also possible that the phrase is specifically intended to be ambiguous. Artists and people titling exhibitions tend to like that kind of thing.